# How do i reset a useref to null in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-ref

I am using useref to display dynamic content

let refValue= useRef(null);

When there is new data, the data is getting overlapped with old data which has to be cleared, but the old data is still retaining with ref, how do i overcome this and clear the old data

Comment: the new data is updated props? 
Could you detail how the data is being updated and where is it coming from?

Comment: Yes, i am passing new data as props and it is updated one

Comment: you can use a `useEffect` with the relevant prop in the dependency array and overwriting `refValue.current`

Comment: how doi update the ref.current in useeffect, this might be a silly question, but i am using ref for the first time

Comment: Even if you mutate your ref, it will not re-render: 

From the documentation: "Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render."

Comment: Just write `refValue.current = null`

Answer (score 0):

Since refs do not notify when it changes you can use a callback.
Documentation: [useRef Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Here is an example using a callback.
Bear in mind that you probably don't need to pass the dependency in the callback, in the example I did it to force the change.

```js
const {
  useState,
useEffect,
useCallback,
} = React;


const CompWithRef = ({title}) => {
const [myRef, setRef] = useState(null);

  const myRefCallback = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setRef(title);
    }
  }, [title]);

  
return (
    <div>
      <p ref={myRefCallback}>Prop title = {title} </p>
      <p>When your ref changes update state, ref state value = {myRef}</p>
    </div>)
  
};

const Example = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('initial title');

  setTimeout(function(){ setTitle("Title is updated"); }, 3000);
 

  return ( 
  <CompWithRef title={title}/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <Example /> ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```